# CSS Transformation Create Door open effect and stay open

Tags: css-transforms

HI I am playing with the CSS transform effect I am trying to create 2 divs that open showing the site.  I have this working but when the doors have finished opening they reappear and hide the content, that I am looking to show!!!!!!

How do I keep the doors open when the effect is finished, thanks for any help!!

here is a basic fiddle showing the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/BaHzN/

```
<div id="content">
<div id="leftDoor">LEFTDOOR</div>
<div id="rightDoor">RIGHTDOOR</div>
</div>

#leftDoor{
    background-color:red;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-animation: leftDoorOpen 4s ease 4s; 

}
#rightDoor{
    right:0px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-animation: rightDoorOpen 4s ease 4s; 
}



@-webkit-keyframes leftDoorOpen {
  from {
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
   }
   to {
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(90deg);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
  }

@-webkit-keyframes rightDoorOpen {
  from {
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  to {
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(-90deg);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaHzN/1/)**</kbd>